# Timbre(Clojure), it takes one minute to finish

Tags: clojure, leiningen, timbre

When I run following simple program, it takes one minute until finish after print "after info" message.

`$ lein run -m logger.core`

```
(ns logger.core
  (:require [taoensso.timbre :as timbre]))

(defn -main []
  (println "before info")
  (timbre/info "hello world")
  (println "after info"))
```

If I comment out `(timbre/info "hello world")`, that waste of time disappears completely.

What is the reason? How can I avoid from this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to shutdown agents.

```
(ns logger.core
  (:require [taoensso.timbre :as timbre]))

(defn -main []
  (println "before info")
  (timbre/info "hello world")
  (shutdown-agents)
  (println "after info"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I could avoid from the situation.

Answer (score -1):

Because most likely Leiningen is also compiling Timbre library and all of its dependencies.